# VB.net Linq Expression from ListItemCollection to List(Of Guid)

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects

I want to do something like this:

```
Dim selectedCourses As List(Of Guid) = From item In chkListCourses.Items Where item.Selected = True Select item.Value
```

but I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Object,System.Object]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]'.

The value of item is a string representation of a Guid.

I'd also like the syntax for a Lambda expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your code to this:

```
Dim selectedCourses As List(Of Guid) = (From item In chkListCourses.Items Where item.Selected = True Select New Guid(item.Value)).ToList(Of Guid)
```

Comment: I get an error at New Guid(item.Value)  

Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'New' can be called without a narrowing conversion:
    'Public Sub New(g As String)': Argument matching parameter 'g' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'.
    'Public Sub New(b() As Byte)': Argument matching parameter 'b' narrows from 'Object' to '1-dimensional array of Byte'.

Comment: Oh sorry :D I thought it's C#. Change it to this:
Dim selectedCourses As List(Of Guid) = (From item in chkListCourses.Items Where item.Selected = True Select Id = New Guid(item.Value)).ToList(Of Guid)

Comment: Just cast item.Value to a string: CStr(item.Value)